Embed custom list into beamer template
I would like to know how to use this custom list into a beamer template from overleaf. When I try to do this, I get some errors for example:

Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoColorEmoji" cannot be found.
LaTeX Error: Command \labelenumi undefined.

The package defines new bullet points in enumerate. Code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\newfontfamily\emojifont[Renderer=Harfbuzz,SizeFeatures={Size=6}]{NotoColorEmoji.ttf}

\newcount\duckcount
\newcount\eggcount
\newcount\chickcount

\def\duck#1{%
\duckcount=\value{#1}%
\loop{\emojifont\Uchar"1F986}%
\advance\duckcount by -1
\unless\ifnum\duckcount=0 
\repeat}

\def\duckegg#1{%
\eggcount=\value{#1}%
\loop{\emojifont\Uchar"1F95A}%
\advance\eggcount by -1
\unless\ifnum\eggcount=0 
\repeat}

\def\duckchick#1{%
\chickcount=\value{#1}%
\loop{\emojifont\Uchar"1F424}%
\advance\chickcount by -1
\unless\ifnum\chickcount=0 
\repeat}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\duck{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\duck{enumi}.\duckegg{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\duck{enumi}.\duckegg{enumii}.\duckegg{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\duck{enumi}.\duckegg{enumii}.\duckegg{enumiii}.\duckchick{enumiv}} 

\begin{enumerate}
\item A duck
\item More ducks
\item A flurry of ducks
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Ducks and eggs
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Do I see... 
    \item Ducks and pre-ducks 
       \begin{enumerate}
       \item Awww...
       \item So cute!
       \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\item Back to ducks
\item Again
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}

Template code:
    \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage {mathtools}
\usepackage{utopia} %font utopia imported
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
% -------------- DUCKS

%-------------------------------------

% set colors
\definecolor{myNewColorA}{RGB}{126,12,110}
\definecolor{myNewColorB}{RGB}{165,85,154}
\definecolor{myNewColorC}{RGB}{203,158,197}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=myNewColorC}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{bg=myNewColorB, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{titlelike}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=myNewColorA, fg = white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=myNewColorA}
\setbeamercolor*{caption name}{fg=myNewColorA}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%------------------------------------------------------------


\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{subtitle}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{date}{size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\small}
\title[]{Mathematical Logic}
\subtitle{SS 2024}
\author[Adam ]{}

\institute[]{Introduction}
\date[\today]
{}

%------------------------------------------------------------
%This block of commands puts the table of contents at the 
%beginning of each section and highlights the current section:
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame}
%    \frametitle{Contents}
%    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
%  \end{frame}
%}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%The next statement creates the title page.
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Introduction}
    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 3 tries only (2 exam appointments each year)
        \item 50\% to pass
        \item Mandatory module
        \item 50\% of the weekly homework to get the exam admission
        
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}

\section{Propositional Calculus}
    \begin{frame}{Propositional Calculus}
    What is a word? What is a chess figure? 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item I WANT DUCKS HERE :)
        
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
    
\section{Conclusion}
    \begin{frame}{Conclusion}
    
    \end{frame}



\section*{Acknowledgement}  
\begin{frame}
\textcolor{myNewColorA}{\Huge{\centerline{Thank you!}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

Thank you!

please do not use external links, your question is archived here forever and will not make sense if the code at the link changes. Make a small complete document that shows the problem and add as a code block in the question. Also those links do not work at all unless you have an account at the external site.

OK will do, thank you!

Hope this is fine now, sorry I'm new here :)

Unrelated to the problem, but you don't need to load \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}, \usepackage{graphicx} or \usepackage{hyperref} in your beamer template

You can increase the number of people who can potentially help you by not using packages like xeCJK

I deleted all those packages you mentioned.

You could define a custom enumerate item template and add ducks there:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikzducks}


\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{
  \foreach \macro in {1,...,\insertenumlabel}{%
    \tikz\duck[scale=0.1];%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 3 tries only (2 exam appointments each year)
        \item 50\% to pass
        \item Mandatory module
        \item 50\% of the weekly homework to get the exam admission
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}


\end{document}



Thank you very much! Did you just create the package tikzducks? I would like to understand how this solution works, for example in case I want to use dogs instead of ducks? Have a great day!

@Adam I happened to already have the tikzducks package :) Find more animals at https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings Or you can replace the line \tikz\duck[scale=0.1];% with an image or emoji of your choice.
